# Why is my refrigerator over-cooling to the point of freezing?

Tags: refrigerator

Whirlpool  Mod.# GB2FHDXWQ01 Ser. # K02883627

With no change in use habits, temp dropped well below freezing in refer ruining produce in crisper drawers. Raising set temp has not raised box temp. This happened once about a year ago and seemed to self correct after some time. Nothing I did then seemed to help, same now. Why? Thanks.

Also, periodically, this thing will fill bottom of freezer (below frig.) with ice til water overflows basin. Easy to deice but a pain and now less than a week since last icing. turned off ice maker, no help. Temp now set at 3 out of 7 and holding right at 32 on bot shelf. 7 was usual set #. I hesitate to start replacing parts with no real idea what's happening. Jim.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If a 'fridge keeps cooling after it's too cool, then there's something wrong with the controls. Replace the thermostat? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks. As just added above, i hesitate to start replacing parts till I know what the problem(s) is/are & since problems come and go, Jim.

Comment: Thanks all. Haven't had time to fool with it yet. Tomorrow. This site https://www.appliancerepair.net/refrigerator-repair-6.html has been helpful too for a non-refrigerator guy, Jim.

Comment: Just checked "Repair Clinic", Thank You! Jim.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bad Damper Control Assembly. Your fridge pulls cold air from the freezer section and more modern models tend to have an electronic controlled port that opens and closes to regulate the fridge temp. If the fridge is too warm or cold, the assembly is letting too much or too little in.

That part is not terribly expensive (showing around $60 at various online retailers for your model) and seems to be easily replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the temperature control is failing. It would seem that the defrost cycle is still working since you see water underneath now and then. This hints toward the main control board. A quick search turns up [this one](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Main-Control-Board/WPW10503278/2684578), which may not be the correct part but serves as an example of the thing.

The only thermostat your unit seems to have is for the defrost cycle, but that's to detect heat from the defrost heater and terminate the defrost cycle. I doubt it's the problem.